# How to ensure that a future completes and all its sub future calls before continue execution

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, google-cloud-storage

I have a method that uploads a photo to firebase cloud storage and after that I get the download url for the photo and then update the firebase database document with that url.
My problem here in the **ElevatedButton** callback when I use **uploadProfilePhoto(..).then** the code is executed before **setPersonalPhotoUrl()** method completes its job and set **personalPhotoUrl**.

I tried to use **whenComplete** instead but it didn't work. My thought if not mistaken is that **uploadProfilePhoto(..).then** is completing its future but it does not take into account the completion of that future method **setPersonalPhotoUrl()**. I need help with this.

fields declared:

```
 UploadTask? uploadTask;
 String personalPhotoUrl = '';
```

the update button:

```
                          ElevatedButton(
                          child: Text('Update Info'),
                          onPressed: () async {
                            await uploadProfilePhoto(profilePhotoFile).then((value) async {
                              // Create an instance of ServiceProvider
                              final SP = ServiceProvider(
                                id: currentUserUid!,
                                name: _controllerName.text.trim(),
                                last: _controllerLast.text.trim(),
                                mobile: _controllerMobile.text.trim(),
                                bio: _controllerBio.text.trim(),
                                photo: personalPhotoUrl, //problem here the value is ''
                                serviceId: _selectedServiceId!,
                                subServices: _selectedSubServicesList,
                              );

                              // Create or Update the service provider
                              try {
                                await DbServices(uid: currentUserUid!)
                                    .updateSProviderData(SP)
                                    .then((value) async {
                                  // update the customers collection when the future completes.
                                  final customer = Customer(
                                      uid: currentUserUid!,
                                      name: _controllerName.text.trim(),
                                      isServiceProvider: true);
                                  await DbServices(uid: currentUserUid!).updateCustomer(customer);
                                  // update the user displayname in firebaseauth when the future completes.
                                  final user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
                                  if (user != null) {
                                    await user.updateDisplayName(_controllerName.text.trim());
                                  }
                                });
                              } catch (e) {
                                Utils.ShowSnackBar(e.toString());
                              }
                            });

                            Utils.ShowSnackBar('Updated successfully');
                            Navigator.maybePop(context).then((value) {
                              if (value == false) {
                                Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => Home(),
                                    ));
                              }
                            });
                          })
```

This is upload photo method which uploads the given photo to FiresStore cloud storage:

```
  Future uploadProfilePhoto(File? photoFile) async {
      if (photoFile == null) return;
      const path = 'images/profile_photo.jpg';
      final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(path);
  
      try {
        uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(photoFile);
        uploadTask?.snapshotEvents.listen((TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) async {
          switch (taskSnapshot.state) {
            ....
            case TaskState.success:
              setPersonalPhotoUrl(storageRef);
              break;
          }
        });
      } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
        // do something
        print('ERROR: Exception thrown when uploading the image: $e');
      }
  }
```

and this method will be called from within **uploadProfilePhoto** and set the url:

```
  void setPersonalPhotoUrl(Reference storageRef) async {
      personalPhotoUrl = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();
  }
```

I don't won't to update the db document before I make sure that the photo is uploaded and later I want to inform the user that if the photo failed to upload and maybe then set the document field to an empty string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1. Refactor your upload function to.**

```
Future uploadProfilePhoto(
      File? photoFile, ValueSetter<TaskSnapshot> resultCallBack) async {
    if (photoFile == null) return;
    const path = 'images/profile_photo.jpg';
    final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(path);

    try {
      UploadTask? uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(photoFile);
      uploadTask.snapshotEvents.listen((TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) async {
        resultCallBack(taskSnapshot);
      });
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      // do something
      print('ERROR: Exception thrown when uploading the image: $e');
    }
  }
```

**2. Can then use it like**

```
onPressed: () async {
      await uploadProfilePhoto(
          profilePhotoFile, (TaskSnapshot taskSnapshotResult) {
        // all the results you need are available in taskSnapshotResult
            if(taskSnapshotResult.state == TaskState.success){
              /// can do what ever you like here

         .... // Create an instance of ServiceProvider
                          final SP = ServiceProvider( ..... blah blah blah
                           
            }
          });
}
```

Comment: Thank u. It worked but not completely so I changed it a little bit. First I need to pass two params to that ValueSetter so I made it as a Map like this:  **"Future uploadProfilePhoto(File? photoFile, ValueSetter<Map<TaskSnapshot, Reference>> resultCallback) async {..."**

Comment: and Second I needed to be sure that the document is updated after I got the download url for the photo so I made the call within the elevated button like this: first I tested if the key of the **Map<TaskSnapshot, Reference> is == to TaskState.success**, then called the **setPersonalPhoto(..).then* and inside **"then"** body I execute that db code. So is this good or there is a workaround this, and of course really thank you.

Comment: Great Job. Hope Everything is working properly now?

Comment: Yeah it is, thank you. You draw my attention to a way where the child can notify the parent of a change, it is somehow passing data in opposite direction.

Comment: Exactly. Don't forget to tick the answer.